# Has anyone else noticed springy controls in Battlefield 3 (PS3)?

Tags: ps3, battlefield-3, controllers

Playing Battlefield 3 on my PS3, the controls feel very springy. When I, for example, quickly rotate right with the left analog stick, my character also rotates a bit to the left when the analog stick is released. It's subtle, but incredibly annoying. I didn't have this problem with BFBC2, and I've tried several controllers. No matter what sensitivity I choose, I can't make quick movements with the analog sticks without the controls "springing back".

Has anyone else noticed this, or is there some kind of fix?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is your character does kind of sway to a stop when sprinting and sway while sprinting. I have never noticed anything abnormal though. Just movements based on the way your body would move.

Comment: I've noticed this a little on 360, but only while in a tank. Usually its a non-issue, as it only happens while sitting still.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are letting go of your analog stick entirely when in the far right position. If that's the case, the left movement when released is due to the spring recoil of the stick. It is going to try to re-center itself but the momentum will keep it going a little past the center resulting in the twitch.

If your stick is loose, but still springy, the effect will be pronounced.

It is an unavoidable effect if you release it in this manner. Don't let go and use your thumb to bring it back easily to the center position.

If you are comfortable taking apart your controller, you may want to consider looking at the 2 axis joystick components. You may be able to tighten them to an extent. Cleaning off any lube would potentially help make the movement 'stickier', but be careful not to clean off too much as you could go too far making it annoyingly sticky.

Comment: That sounds like it might be it. Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately I'm not near my ps3 so I can't verify this just yet.